# Spring JPA prevent read from cache

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In a Spring boot application using `jpa` i want to capture changes to an entity.

Before persisting the changes to the database i make a query using `CrudRepository` to get the state of the current entity before persisting, so i can map the changes that will be done.

The problem is that the last query to the database is reading from cache, and thus is the same as the entity i want to persist

```
entity.removeObjects(list);

Entity persisted = repository.findById(entity.getId());
```

`persisted` is now the same as `entity` and it has also removed all items in `list`, but i need it to be how entity was before calling `.remove`

I've tried using `@Transactional` without any luck

Comment: From where do you get the `entity`?

Comment: Same way i get the persisted. By `repository.findById(id)`

Comment: Then I am not entirely sure what you're expecting. Calling `repository.findById(id)` two times will always return the same entity

Comment: The problem is that i make changes to the first entity, and then when i try to get a fresh one from the database (before persisting the first), the changes made to the first one is also present on the second one i just got from the database

Comment: You don't get a "fresh" one from the database, that's the problem, you get the one managed by JPA, which is **exactly** the same that you fetched earlier: `repository.findById(id) == repository.findById(id)` will yield `true`

Comment: Why exactly do you need to fetch the "persisted" entity in the first place?

Comment: Hibernate Envers does entity auditing (change logging) for you out-of-the-box or use something like Javers. Also if you want to detect changes you need to dig into the depths of Hibernate/JPA and write an entity listener which will get you the old and new state and there you can calculate the difference.